# How to disable Joomla Unique Email Functionality?

Tags: joomla

I have a site with Joomla 1.5.25. I have user login facilty with the site. I have modified Joomla's default functionality. Also I have created a user acount via php MyAdmin and entered so many data approximatly 1200 user entry.

But now I face a problem with the Email at Joomla backend.

When I trying to changed the Email ID via the back-end(user managment), its fires an error that:

> "Email Id alread in used."

So here I want to change this Unique Email validation and it allow me to enter the Email ID if its already used by other one. Is ther any way or patch to set it disable?

Thanks!

Comment: Disabling or removing that universally is a bad idea and would require core hacks to accomplish. Why would you want duplicate email addresses for users? It will cause problems and is a security issue.

Comment: Actually My I have any area for registration in football club. have two login for site 1) as player login and 2) captain login two manage the team. So The person who register it self can be player and may also be captain of Team. So they people want to use their one email ID for both the as player and as a captain as while they creat their Account. That why i need to solve the above problem.

Comment: Rather than much about with the login system, why not use a plugin to add a manager flag to a standard user account? Then that person can do both player and manager functions without having to hack up the core and making updating a pain.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "easy" solution to work with duplicated emails.
But if you really need to do it, you have to override JTableUser (see line 230) and take care of sideffects like the ability to reset a password on com_users.

Comment: I found the solution and I did same  as you say,